# C# Geting null value from other form

Tags: c#, forms, get, null

I'm working on a school project and i get stuck in getting values to form from another form.

I want to send the information from TextBox1 , Form 4 to label1 Form5.

I used this code in FORM 5, setting the Modify propriety of TextBox1 from FORM 4 to Public.

```
  public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private Form4 otherForm = new Form4();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label2.Text = otherForm.textBox1.Text; 
    }
```

And even if I type something in Text Box1, when i Run the program, it shows me that the value it's Null.

Comment: This is a very common error. You have created a NEW instance of Form4 and you are trying to extract info from that instance. This instance is not the other instance of Form4 already active on your screen.

Comment: Agree with Steve. It is common to think of Forms as special magic "things", [but they are just classes](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/forms-are-just-classes/) and the same rules apply.

Comment: Here you can find an example with a solution for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922886/c-data-transfer-between-two-forms?rq=1

Comment: I still don't understand how to solve the problem...

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Form4 frm4 = new Form4(this);
                frm4.Show();
                label1.Text = frm4.textBox1.Text;

        }